# need help in creating time slots

Tags: iphone, objective-c, puzzle

I have a UITableView and I want each row to represent a 15 minute time slot, for example row 0 to 3 would have 7:00-7:15, 7:15-7:30, 7:30-7:45, 7:45-08:00 respectively. I don't want to hard code all of this value into an array or so, so 
is it possible to convert:

```
0,1,2,3 to 1
4,5,6,7 to 2
8,9,10,11 to 3
```

etc.

If yes how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0,1,2,3 to 1
4,5,6,7 to 2
8,9,10,11 to 3
```

```
(number/4) + 1;
```